# VBA Error Code 438 - Most likely setting active worksheet issue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working off of code I found via google. Originally the code was set up to create a new summary sheet, however I'd like to use one that already exists and paste the new data in the next empty row. The issue seems to happen when I set the summary worksheet. I'm getting a "Run-time error '438'" on this line of code -

`Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Tab_Upload").Activate`

when I use the following code:

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With


' Set Summary Worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Tab_Upload").Activate

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 1)) = "_" Then

        ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
        Last = DestSh.[a65536].End(xlUp).Row

        ' Specify the range to place the data.
        Set CopyRng = sh.Rows("A23,B8:S8")

        ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
        ' worksheet to copy all the data.
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
               "summary worksheet to place the data."
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        ' This statement copies values and formats from each
        ' worksheet.
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With



    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

`Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Tab_Upload").Activate`

to

`Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab_Upload")`

You have missed `s` in the end of `Worksheets`

Comment: That didn't seem to work although this does:     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab_Upload").Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Comment: I've updated my answer. You've missed `s` in `Worksheets`. Try now

Comment: @TessD  Just so you know, what you're doing in the code you put in the comment isn't actually fixing the error.  It's just hiding it from display and skipping over the offending line of code.  It's not a solution and if you use it, you will get unexpected results.  The times when you should wrap your code in On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0 is few and far between.  Don't fall in to the trap thinking that you've solved it by ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize it did that... This is all a learning experience for me.